# Why $\sum _ {n = x}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left (n^{1/n} - 1 \right) $ gives so many repeating 0 s here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics

$\sum _ {n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left (n^{1/n} - 1 \right) $ is the [MRB constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MRB_constant).

Whether it's rational or not I know its terms and all of its partial sums are irrational.

So why does $\sum _ {n = x}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left (n^{1/n} - 1 \right) $ gives so many repeating 0 s here?

Specifically, I found the following that I would like some insight into.

Using Mathematica,

```
f[x_] :=NSum[(-1)^n (n^(1/n) - 1), {n, x, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision ->200]

 Table[N[(10 f[10^(10 n)])/Log[10], 10 n + 5], {n, 1, 10}] // TableForm
```

gives the following:

{"5.00000000599560537540642761618*^-9"},
{"1.0000000000000000002351499356789287554825*^-18"},
{"1.5000000000000000000000000000525473072303184465947*^-28"},
{"2.0000000000000000000000000000000000000093092546357714246065*^-38"},
{"2.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014515071095008027395*^-48"},
{"3.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020872180100741653026*^-58"},
{"3.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000283805816529723015*^-68"},
{"4.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000370402757516999728*^-78"},
{"4.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046851262396924667*^-88"},
{"5.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000057813541588646383970880658544811814*^-98"}

I know that $$x^{1/x} = e^{\frac {\log x} {x}},$$

but I still don't see where all the repeating 0s come from.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you would expect if $$\sum _ {n = x}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left (n^{1/n} - 1 \right) \approx \frac12 (-1)^x \frac{\log_e(x)}{x}$$  with the error being much smaller - perhaps of the order of the square of that.

For example if $x=10^{10}$ (your first example) this would suggest about  $\frac 12 10 \log_e(10) \times 10^{-10}\approx 1.151293\times 10^{-9}$ but you divide this by $\log_e(10)$ so getting $5 \times 10^{-9}$ with an error of around $5.9956 \times 10^{-18}$ so getting several zeros.

Meanwhile with  $x=10^{100}$ (your last example) this would suggest about $\frac 12 100 \log_e(10) \times 10^{-100}$ but you divide this by $\log_e(10)$ so getting $5 \times 10^{-98}$ with an error of around $5.78 \times 10^{-196}$ so getting many more zeros.

Comment: Henry, I know that Series[(n^(1/n) - 1 ), {n, Infinity, 1}] gives Log[x]/x+an error, but does the 1/2 come from the (-1)^n? And where does the "divide this by loge(10)" come from?

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns You have `/Log[10]` in your Mathematica code.

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns  For large $x$ each term is about $(-1)^x \frac{\log_e(x)}{x}$ so adding this to about $\frac12(-1)^{x-1} \frac{\log_e(x-1)}{x-1} \approx -\frac12(-1)^{x} \frac{\log_e(x)}{x}$ gives about $\frac12(-1)^{x} \frac{\log_e(x)}{x}$.  You get something similar with $\sum _ {n = x}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{1}{n} \approx  \frac12 (-1)^x \frac1x$

Comment: thank you! That hits the spot.